# IMAP, What is proper for multi-data responses?

Tags: email, imap

If I have an IMAP FETCH,

```
12 UID FETCH 3 (BODY.PEEK[HEADER] BODY.PEEK[TEXT])
```

And I respond with a

```
* 3 FETCH (UID 3 BODY[HEADER] {322}
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8;format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Date: Fri, 07 Aug 2015 16:36:44 -0400
From: myemail@email.email
To: myemail@email.email
Subject: subjecct
Message-ID: <eea78aff8bfdfgvdfgvdgcdg655d14a4a7@email.email>
X-Sender: myemail@email.email
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/0.9.5
 BODY[TEXT] {14}
myemailstuff
)
```

All is CRLF, the 322 properly says the length of the first block, from the CRLF after that line containing 322, to the CRLF before the `BODY[TEXT] {14}` (take note of the space before `BODY`).

From there, I add a space, and then the `BODY[TEXT] {14}`, etc. This doesn't work. I can't even find the specs in RFC 3501 for a single one, yet alone two in a row. Does anyone know where the specifications are for this, specifically, or know it off the top of their head?

Also, if it matters, this error came directly from an iPhone, and the server is my own(the embedded one in Avuna).

Comment: I deleted my answer since you clarified.  Did you send a 12 OK after?  Do you get a specific error?  In general, for formatting responses you pretend your {X}CRLF[x bytes] is just a single token like any other imap list item (quoted string or atom), with normal delimiters on either side (spaces, closing parentheses, etc).

Comment: @Max That's exactly what I did. I find it unlikely, but seemingly plausible that Apple's software may not be following the RFC?

Comment: I doubt it.  You may want to consider adding another CRLF after your headers... Otherwise, perhaps a smaller example with a hex dump might help.

Comment: @Max Do you know what these structures are called?

Comment: There's bnf at the end of the rfc, which should have the names. Like qstring or atom.

Comment: @Max Your idea of adding a new CRLF was 90% the answer. I also had to stop performing a `trim()` on it before sending it which I think was causing an overflow. You can post that as an answer since it solved my problem. :)

Comment: Ah yes, if you trim(), you would have removed the CRLF from the last lines of the headers... I have added an answer as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal takes the place of a quoted string or atom, and should have delimiters on either side the same way.  That is `{322}\r\n[322 bytes]` should be treated exactly as a quoted string, with a space before and a space or parenthesis after.

I do not see any obvious problem with your sample, however, you may want to consider putting an extra CRLF in your headers in your literal, which may make some MIME parsers happier.